# Why is this text where it is?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML page and for some reason the text is going outside of where it should.
[Here is an image of this. Note this image is cut smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYrvQ.png)
The text in the image should have been in the gray area.

I am not the best at CSS and HTML so this might be obvious.

I have tried to fix it but nothing i did work it only made it worse when ever i tried to fix it.

Here is the code.

```css
#screen {
    position: fixed;
    background: none;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#levels {
    position: fixed;
    background: black;
    left: calc(50% - 224px);
    top: 0px;
    width: 448px;
    height: 126px;
}

#rockCount {
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
    left: calc(50% - 128px);
    top: 84px;
    width: 256px;
    height: 32px;
}

.level {
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin-left: 64px;
    float: left;
}

#rock {
    position: fixed;
    background: black;
    left: calc(50% - 128px);
    top: calc(50% - 128px);
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Stone breaker</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="screen">
            <div id="levels">
                <div class="level" id="level0"></div>
                <div class="level" id="level1"></div>
                <div class="level" id="level2"></div>
                <div id="rockCount">
                    <div id="countText">Rocks destroyed: 0/10</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="rock"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all, you should only use the 'div' element when there is no *better* tag avaliable. You can find an overview of the different tags here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/

Regarding your problem, i'd say it's because of the following css:

```css
#rockCount {
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
    left: calc(50% - 128px);
    top: 84px;
    width: 256px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

You say that the  element should be positioned relative to its current position. And then you say that it should be position 84px down from this position.

You can read more about positioning here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: I think i might have found a tutorial video that was completely wrong because in the video they said position: relative would place the element based on it's parent and the position: absolute as what relative accually is.